# Pimp a bar chart with predefined colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bar chart like this:

```
cyl.am <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(am)))
cyl.am +
 geom_bar()
```

I would like to spice it up a little with my own colours. However when I do:

```
cbbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00")
cyl.am +
 geom_bar() +
 scale_fill_brewer(palette = cbbPalette)
```

I get the following warning message, any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (!palette %in% unlist(brewer)) { :
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In pal_name(palette, type) : Unknown palette #000000#E69F00
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `scale_fill_manual` instead:

```
cbbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00")
cyl.am <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(am)))

cyl.am +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cbbPalette)
```

[image]